# How can I create a chatbot application where the user can create its own bot?

Tags: natural-language-processing, ai-design, chat-bots

I am trying to create a chatbot application where the user can create its own bot, like [Botengine](https://www.botengine.ai/). After going through google, I saw I need some NLP API to process the user's query. As per wit.ai [basic example](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart), I can set and get data. How I am going to create a bot engine?

So, as far I understand the flow, here is an example for pizza delivery

1. The user will enter a welcome message, i.e - Hi or Hello
2. The welcome reply will be saved by bot owner in my database
3. The user will enter some query, then I will hit wit.ai API to process that query. Example: The user's query is "What kind of pizza's available in your store" and wit.ai will respond with the details of intent "pizza_type"
4. Then I will search for the intent returned by wit in my database.

So, is that the right flow to create a chatbot? Am I in the right direction? Could anyone give me some link or some example so I can go through it? I want to create this application using Node.js. I have also found some example in [node-wit](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit), but can't find how I will implement this.

Comment: We can give you a glimpse from where to start, however can you go through the community guidelines.Just a little bit.Can you give us a link to your project if you don't mind!

Comment: I am working  on my local, and I could not make so much progress so I can share you. All I need a basic knowledge to start the project.